# convert array to mongo ObjectID.....nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an object in nodejs :

```
 let id = {"0":94,"1":132,"2":212,"3":194,"4":74,"5":37,"6":102,"7":242,"8":31,"9":49,"10":96,"11":178}
```

I want to convert this to a mongo ObjectId. I tried this:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
var objectId = new ObjectID(id);
```

This throws an error saying:

```
Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

How do I convert my array to a valid mongo ObjectID? Thanks

Comment: where is your array? id is an Object.

Comment: what these array values signify?  because ObjectId is the combination of timestamp, a random value, and increment counter. 
see here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid

Comment: @VijayRajpurohit - I got these values from mongo. This is a restful api call and i send this back to the client and the client sends this back to the api.

Comment: @BoundForGlory : So `new ObjectID(id)` : Here `id` should strictly be a string, First you need to convert object to string & then do `ObjectID()` !! So to be said you can't do it with above given sample object as when you convert it to string it will exceed character limit of `24` (`941322121947437102242314996178`) has to be trimmed down to 24 characters !!

Comment: exception clearly states that you must pass string of 24 hex characters. But you have passed not string but object.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to convert Object to Mongo Object Id?

Are you sure you want to convert this Object to Mongo Object Id?

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/

I may be wrong. But usually people store that kind of data to mongodb collection and reference that collection with dynamically created MongoID.

Comment: I need it for lookups. I'll be doing a ton of these and I will have the array of characters that i got from mongo. This is part of a restful api call